# Linux Deploy removal

Tags: root-access, linux

I was going to install [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy) , but then if I don't like it how can I remove the Linux installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this for myself by navigating to **Settings > Storage**, tap on the **Misc** category, select the ~4 GB linux image and use the trash icon to delete it, but this will probably vary depending on what device you use.